# PostgreSQL many scalar functions on same unnest

Tags: postgresql

I have this query:

```
select distinct * ,  
       (select count(A) filter(where A < 360) from unnest(cust_journey_time_series) as A) as count_journey_time_series  
     , (select avg(A) filter(where A < 360) from unnest(cust_journey_time_series) as A) as avg_journey_time_series  
     , (select sum(A)  filter(where A < 360) from unnest(cust_journey_time_series) as A) as order_journey_time
     , (select sum(A)  .. 
     , (select count(distinct A) ..  
from (
 select a,b,c, max(s) s, max(ev) ev, max(ord) ord,
     array_agg(cust_journey_time_seconds order by ev asc) as cust_journey_time_series, min(mi) mi,
    array_agg(col order by ev asc)  as cus,
     min(ra) ra, max(de) de, max(to) to,
    max(orde) orde, max(cam) cam, 
    max(pag) pag,
    count(collec) FILTER (WHERE collec <> las )  AS  pag_count,
 
    max (fi)  as ad,
    array_agg(fi)  as dd2c,
    array_agg(ut)  as ut_places,
     array_agg(ct)  as ct_places,
     array_agg(ut)  as utaces
    
from temp_j
     group by a,b,c
     
     order by ev
 )aaa
```

my intuitive code would be `select distinct * , (select count(A), sum(A),avg(A) filter(where A < 360) from unnest(cust_journey_time_series) as A) as count_journey_time_series, sum_journey_time_series , avg_journey_time_series`

but I get this error

> subquery must return only one column

Is there a way to optimize the query or PostgreSQL does it under the hood?

Comment: You could put the `unnest` in the from clause (which is recommended anyway): `from (select ...) as t cross join unnest(cust_journey_time_series) as u(a)` - but without more details it's impossible to give a better answer.

Comment: Note that `distinct *` is a code smell. It's typically more efficient to avoid generating duplicates in earlier steps (e.g. by not using a join, but EXISTS condition or aggregating _before_ join or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to translate the fragment you provide to something better:

```
select distinct tab.*,  
       count(cjts.A) filter (where cjts.A < 360) as count_journey_time_series,
       avg(cjts.A) filter (where cjts.A < 360) as avg_journey_time_series,
       sum(cjts.A) filter (where cjts.A < 360) as order_journey_time,
       ...
from (select ...) as tab
   cross join lateral unnest(tab.cust_journey_time_series) as cjts
group by tab.pkey;
```

That way, you have to evaluate the function only once.

The error message of your modified query comes from:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT count(A), sum(A), avg(A) FROM ...)
...
```

That is not allowed. You can only use a single result column in a subquery in the `SELECT` list. Writing the query my way avoids the problem.

Comment: Is there a way to use `cross join lateral` without a group by? in my query the aggregation is done in the subquery. On top of it I add columns with features, calculated from the aggregated columns.

Comment: You need the `GROUP BY`, and I don't see a problem with it

Comment: If I use the group by, I have to group by also cjts which duplicates rows for each value in the cjts.

Comment: No, because the `cjts` appear only inside aggregate functions.